# How to extract Table data using regular expressions?

Tags: list-manipulation, regular-expressions

For example, the `Table` have follows structure:

```
Data = {
  {userid , 1 , brith , 24},
  {math , 90, art , 96, sport, 72 , econmic , 98},
  {userid , 2 , brith, 23},
  {math , 80 , art , 86, sport , 92 , econmic , 92},
  {userid , 3, brith , 25},
  {math , 90 , art, 76 , sport , 82 , econmic, 99},
  {userid, 1, phonenumber , 9157678481},
  {country, UK},
  {userid , 2, phonenumber, 9237678481},
  {country , USA}
  }
```

My question is how to use regular expressions to extract `useid, 1` 's data.

Expect result is

```
{{userid , 1 , brith , 24},
{math , 90, art , 96, sport, 72 , econmic , 98},
{userid, 1, phonenumber , 9157678481},
{country, UK}}
```

Any comments very much appreciate!

Comment: how about `Join @@ Select[#[[1, 2]] == 1 &]@Split[Data, #[[1]] == userid &]`?

Comment: Here is another possibility using pattern: `Flatten[Cases[Partition[Data, 2], {{userid, 1, __}, {__}}], 1]`

Comment: All works, thanks to all comments!

Comment: I see, `__` is the `BlankSequence`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### [SequenceCases](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SequenceCases.html)

```
SequenceCases[data, p : {{_, 1, __}, _} :> Sequence @@ p]
```

[image]

### [Split](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Split.html) + [Select](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Select.html)

```
Join @@ Select[#[[1, 2]] == 1 &] @ Split[data, #[[1]] == userid &]
```

[image]

### [Split](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Split.html) + [Cases](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Cases.html)

```
Cases[p : {{_, 1, __}, __} :> Sequence @@ p] @ Split[data, #[[1]] == userid &]
```

[image]

Comment: Owesome! How did you do that! `SequenceCases` is very helpful. if I want remove the expect result like `{{userid , 1 , brith , 24},
{math , 90, art , 96, sport, 72 , econmic , 98},
{userid, 1, phonenumber , 9157678481},
{country, UK}}` from `Data` Table, which method can be choose?  just some tips very be helpful!

Comment: @Ben, try `SequenceCases[data, p : {{userid, Except[1], __}, _} :> Sequence @@ p]` or `DeleteCases[data, 
 Alternatives @@ 
  SequenceCases[data, p : {{_, 1, __}, _} :> Sequence @@ p]]`

Comment: Ace! Thank you so much!

Comment: Also: `Catenate@SequenceCases[data, {{_, 1, __}, _}]`